# Filter report using current ID

Tags: custom-object, custom-report-type, page-layout

I have a report. The idea is, in a standard layout, when i embed the report, to filter it by the current if of the record that is being viewed

**Example**: xxx.salesforce.com/b0UI000000CuzXXXXX

Is it possible to filter like `'Object ID equals "b0UI000000CuzXXXXX"'`?

Best regards

Comment: Are you adding a report chart to a page layout?

Comment: @DanielHoechst Yes, I am, but I guess it works the same way as for reports only?

Comment: Have you looked at https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_embed_chartdialog_contextfilter.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks @DanielHoechst , I didn't know you could go up to 4 levels now in Report Types, it solves problem (or rather, there isn't a problem anymore). Thank you!